# SQL Server: fast index fragmentation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing

I have SQL Server 2008 Web Edition with database file about 50 GB, the main table contains about 100 million record.

Everyday we have about 100,000-200,000 new rows.

The table contains 7 non clustered indices, one of those non clustered indices is on VARCHAR column and usually contains 10-25 characters, now my question is, why every time I reorganize this index  it's got fragmented very very fast, let's say in one day it will be 30-40% fragmented!

I have to mention that when inserting each new row, this column will has null value, and then when more info is available this column value will be updated once, and no more update actions made for this column.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks. Abed

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your writes are at random positions in the index B-trees. Consider using `FILLFACTOR` to provide space for those writes.